# Как написать "тестирующую" систему (pyhton)

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты

Допустим я получаю файл содержания:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a + b)
```

Далее мне нужно проверить верна ли выведенная в консоль информация. Я бы делал это через `assert`, но я не понимаю, как мне получить результат работы программы.

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Научитесь запускать программу переопределив у неё входной и выходной потоки: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run . Осторожнее - будет сложно.

Comment: Другой вариант - `os.system` запускает команду которая перенаправляет вход и выход в файлы (команду вам надо будет придумать). Когда команда отработала, проверяете содержимое выходного файла. Это проще.